# ASP.NET MVC 5 Page Controlled by Active Directory Group

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

Is it possible to create a page (View) that is strictly controlled by an Active Directory Group?

There is no login for this page, if you are a member of the "VIP" Active Directory group, then the page is rendered, otherwise if not then you can't see it.

Comment: It is yes... but you need to store your own mapping of which groups can access which Views.

Comment: Do you have any code samples or point me where to look?

Comment: sure.. I'll put an answer together for you. Do you already have code for accessing AD Groups?

Comment: Not yet but I think that is pretty straight forward, it's more so how to apply it to the page/view. I'm not sure if I need to configure IIS to make this all work. Currently the view contains some information, anyone can view it (they're already logged on to their windows machine with their AD logins), no login required. Now just need to restrict it to AD groups.

Answer (score 0):

First get your current users windows log in

```
var windowsUserName= HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.WindowsLogin();
```

Then get all the AD groups for your user using the System.DirectoryServices

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

        public List<string> GetUsersActiveDirectoryGroups(string windowsUserName)
        {
            try
            {
                var allUserGroups = new List<string>();

                if (windowsUserName == null) return allUserGroups;

                var domainConnection = new DirectoryEntry();

                var samSearcher = new DirectorySearcher
                {
                    SearchRoot = domainConnection,
                    Filter = "(samAccountName=" + windowsUserName + ")"
                };
                samSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");

                var samResult = samSearcher.FindOne();
                if (samResult == null) return allUserGroups;

                var theUser = samResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
                theUser.RefreshCache(new[] { "tokenGroups" });
                _bet365EmployeeFullName = theUser.Properties["CN"].Value.ToString();

                foreach (byte[] resultBytes in theUser.Properties["tokenGroups"])
                {
                    var mySid = new SecurityIdentifier(resultBytes, 0);

                    var sidSearcher = new DirectorySearcher
                    {
                        SearchRoot = domainConnection,
                        Filter = "(objectSid=" + mySid.Value + ")"
                    };
                    sidSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");

                    var sidResult = sidSearcher.FindOne();
                    if (sidResult != null)
                    {
                        allUserGroups.Add((string)sidResult.Properties["name"][0]);
                    }
                }

                return allUserGroups;
            }
```

You now need to map which groups have access to which view in the application.
Once done, the next step is the restricting of the viewing of "Views".

You need to set up a permissions filter that uses the MVC AuthorizeAttribute. Something like the below.

```
public class PermissionsFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private readonly string _viewName;

        public PermissionsFilter(string viewName)
        {
            _viewName = viewName;
        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
           //Check to see if users groups has access to the view
           //If not redirect to unauthorized page
        }
    }
```

I accomplish the above by have a user object held in session. This contains a list of all the application permissions my user has access too. This is the mapping you need to do. I have all my view names stored in the database along with an ID of which AD groups can access them.

Then finally in the controller, decorate the get action for the view accordingly.

```
[HttpGet]
[PermissionsFilter("ViewName")]
public ActionResult ReturnMyView(int currentFolderID)
 {
    return View(); //Etc..
 }
```

Well hope that helps!